# How to avoid mouseover event when the user's intent is to click

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, promise

I have an element which can be hovered & clicked. On hovering of the element, I show a preview of something but on click I need to completely change the content of page based on click event related logic. Now the problem is when user's intent is to click even then my code is ending up triggering the hover flow because of mouseover event getting triggered first & then the click event. From CX perspective it's not creating any problem but it's actually regressing the latency of webpage because of heavy lifting being done on mouseover flow which is effectively useless since user's intent is to click. One solution I can think of is to wait for some time after mouseover event so that if click event is triggered in the meanwhile, I can drop the hover event. But this solution is not good since it would impact the user's experience when their intent is to actually hover. Can there be any better way to avoid this through JS/jQuery. I can't use any external library.
Thanks

Comment: The only difference between hover and click is whether you click immediately after mousing over the element. And the only way to detect that is by waiting a short time.

Comment: How can the browser possibly read the user's mind to determine their "intent"?

Comment: So just use `setTimeout()` in the mouseover listener, and `clearTimeout()` in the click listener.

Comment: Reduce/streamline/optimise the amount that goes in the mouseover - maybe stage it so the initial mouseover is much quicker *then* does the "heaving lifting"

Comment: You mention a preview, maybe this is becoming the target of the click event.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to read user's mind. So just let the user choose what they want. For an example, you can add a checkbox to turn on/off the hover event, and give a default based on common perference

Answer (score -1):

On your element, try this css content :

```
element{
  cursor: not-allowed;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: That's going to prevent the click event the OP wants to detect.